# Loop over even/odd columns & stack them under specific ones

Tags: r, loops

I have the following data set from Douglas Montgomery's book *Introduction to Time Series Analysis & Forecasting*:

[image]

I created a data frame called pharm from this spreadsheet.  We only have two variables but they're repeated over several columns.   I'd like to take all odd "Week" columns past the 2nd column and stack them under the 1st Week column in order.  Conversely I'd like to do the same thing with the even "Sales, in thousands" columns.  Here's what I've tried so far:

```
pharm2 <- data.frame(week=c(pharm$week, pharm[,3], pharm[,5], pharm[,7]), sales=c(pharm$sales, pharm[,4], pharm[,6], pharm[,8]))
```

This works because there aren't many columns, but I need a way to do this more efficiently because hard coding won't be practical with many columns.  Does anyone know a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the columns are alternating, just subset with a recycling logical vector, `unlist` and create a new data.frame

```
out <- data.frame(week = unlist(pharm[c(TRUE, FALSE)]),
           sales = unlist(pharm[c(FALSE, TRUE)]))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response!  That solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `seq` function to generate sequence to extract alternating columns.

```
pharm2 <- data.frame(week = unlist(pharm[seq(1, ncol(pharm), 2)]), 
                     sales = unlist(pharm[seq(2, ncol(pharm), 2)]))
```